# MDP calculation

Tags: artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

How does the below calculation work?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When you are in state S_{n-2}, the optimal actions are

```
[a0, a0, {a0|a1}, {a0|a1}, {a0|a1}, ...]
```

which will give you this reward sequence:

```
[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, ...]
```

To get the optimal value in S_{n-2} you just have to discount the optimal rewards with `γ`:

```
γ^0*0.0 + γ^1*0.0 + γ^2*1.0 + γ^3*1.0 + γ^4*1.0 + ...
= γ^2 * (1.0 + γ + γ^2 + ...)
= γ^2 * V(G)
```

You get zero intermediate rewards before you reach the goal step. So this is equivalent to discounting the value of G by two time steps.